# ValueError: Shapes (None,) and (None, 150, 150, 6) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am building an image classification model using Keras, SGD, and Softmax activation. The training dataset consists of RGB images with dimensions of 512x384.

To do so, I have followed Keras "Getting Started" guide. However, when I tried to train the model, I got the error mentioned in the title. This is my code so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

FOLDER_PATH = 'dataset'

dataset = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    FOLDER_PATH,
    batch_size=64,
    image_size=(512, 384)
)

# None x None x 3 -> Arbitrarily sized images with 3 channels
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None, None, 3))

x = CenterCrop(height=150, width=150)(inputs)
x = Rescaling(scale= 1.0 / 255)(x)

outputs = layers.Dense(6, activation="softmax")(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01),
    loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
)

model.fit(dataset, epochs=3)
```

This is the model's summary:

```
Model: "model_6"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_8 (InputLayer)        [(None, None, None, 3)]   0         
                                                                 
 center_crop_7 (CenterCrop)  (None, 150, 150, 3)       0         
                                                                 
 rescaling_7 (Rescaling)     (None, 150, 150, 3)       0         
                                                                 
 dense_7 (Dense)             (None, 150, 150, 6)       24        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 24
Trainable params: 24
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I have also checked the shape of my data:

```py
for data, labels in dataset:
   print(data.shape)   # (64, 512, 384, 3)
   print(data.dtype)   # <dtype: 'float32'> 
   print(labels.shape) # (64,) 
   print(labels.dtype) # <dtype: 'int32'>
```

So, how can I fix this? I wonder if I have made some mistake in the data preprocessing pipeline, or if the data I am using is somehow incompatible with the SGD optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change couple things.

first of all, softmax require you to use one-hot encoded labels. You can use the following lines to convert your data:

```
dataset = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    FOLDER_PATH,
    batch_size=64,
    image_size=(512, 384)
)
num_classes = len(dataset.class_names)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (x, tf.one_hot(y, num_classes)))
```

after this step you also need to flatten your input before you feed it to your model. which is done by:

```
x = CenterCrop(height=150, width=150)(inputs)
x = Rescaling(scale= 1.0 / 255)(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x) # add this line here to flatten 
outputs = layers.Dense(6, activation="softmax")(x)
```

dont forget to change your fit:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_onehot, epochs=3)
```

Comment: forgot to mention, make sure you encode your test lables as well

Comment: Hmm... this gives me a "too many values to unpack" error on the `image_dataset_from_directory` invocation. I thought this function returned a `Dataset` instance.

Comment: Yes, I forgot we cant do that anymore, I made the change above it should work now